# Earliest use of the word "gematria" to mean the value of words

Tags: history, words, gematria-numerology

What's the earliest use of the word "gematria" **followed by the use of it to mean the value of the word**? I'm aware that in Pirkei Avot the word itself is used, but that is not used in conjunction with the actual numbering system (and thus it is possible that it means something else in that context). There are also places in the Gemara that use the value system, but in those places it does not use the word "gematria" but rather "sifra" (lit. "the value"). When is the first time the two are used together?

Related (but not the same): [What is the earliest source that mentions Gematria?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/what-is-the-earliest-source-that-mentions-gematria)

Comment: [Nazir 5a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=5&format=pdf) [Yoma 20a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=20&format=pdf) [Megilah 15b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=15b&format=pdf) [Horayot 11b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=28&daf=11b&format=pdf) [Shabbat 149b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=149b&format=pdf) [Niddah 38b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=38b&format=pdf)

Comment: Makos 23b http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=23b&format=text

Comment: @DoubleAA, sam, yes, but which of those is *earliest*? `:-)`