# Conundrum of first verse of Matos & first verse of Masei

Tags: gematria-numerology, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

A fellow pointed out to me that the first verse of Matos & first verse of Masei have the exact same Gematria of 3324. Has anyone seen any Seforim that talk about the similar Gematria between these two verses?

Comment: Since we're on the topic, does anyone talk about whether all gematrios are meaningful, or are some/almost all of them just because everything has a number? Does a gematria need a mesorah or ratification by a mekubal?

Comment: @MichelR https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/is-gematria-accepted-by-all

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/what-is-the-earliest-source-that-mentions-gematria

Comment: These are all a different topic from my question. I think.

Comment: My question is similar to "gezeirah shavah". גזירה שוה is absolutely one of the 13 ways that Chazal do drashos, as valid as you can get. But that doesn't mean that any two words with the same shoresh have a גזירה שוה. Chazal only accept the ones that have a mesorah.

Comment: @MichoelR I believe this new book addresses your question https://www.amazon.com/Gematria-Refigured-Conveys-Through-Numbers/dp/1957579250, although I have not read it myself

Comment: @MIchoelR That is why I gave you a link to ask your question.

Comment: Interesting question and an interesting coincidence.  In addition to these pesukim, in במדבר ל:ב and in במדבר לג:א, there are six additional pesukim in Tanach with this gematria: שמות ו:כט, במדבר כז:ד, דברים לד:ג, שופטים י:יד, ישעיהו נג:ב, ירמיהו מו:כא. Interesting that 5 of the total 8 are in Chumash.  Also interesting that our two in Matos/Masei are at the start of a parsha pesucha/stuma (as expected for a parshas hashavua) and also the pasuk at שמות ו:כט (within Parshas VaEra).